# Does rewarded-ads allow to check what the user got rewarded so far?

Tags: android, admob, rewardedvideoad

### Background

I've recently read about rewarded ads, as shown here:

- https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples
- https://developers.google.com/admob/android/rewarded-video

### The problem

I can't find any API about the recent rewards, of what the user got so far.

### What I've tried

I tried to check on the docs and tried to check all possible functions of the API via the IDE itself.

The samples on Github show how to get a callback that you got a reward (so you can save it for later), but this will be lost in the case of uninstall of the app, or if you switch to another device that has the same app with the same user account.

### The questions

1. Is there a way to get all rewards of the user for the current app (even after uninstall&re-install) ? If so, how?
   If not, what's the best way to do it to fill this gap? Is there one from Google?
2. Is there a way to get what the reward is worth in real money?
3. Are there other similar services like the one of Google, of rewarded videos, that also provide an API to check on recent rewards ?

Comment: No, AdMob will not keep a track of the users earning so far. May be you can try Tapjoy they will help you to maintain the users wallet as well as provide you ads for earning. Here is the link https://www.tapjoy.com/ . But I think it is free up to a certain users please check before using it. Hope it helps.

Comment: @RajeshK To me it sounds such a basic functionality. Which solution does Google provide for this? Save state to Google Drive?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge they do not provide all these kind of services. AdMob will only provide ads. But there are other services as mentioned  earlier such as Tapjoy which can be used to manage your user wallet/earnings easily.

Comment: @RajeshK That's too bad.

Comment: Sorry couldn't understand what is bad, is it AdMob or Tapjoy? If Tapjoy is not up to the mark you can try googling some of these kind of  services. Frankly I do not now any of these services.

Comment: I mean it's too bad Admob doesn't have it. Why didn't you write it all as an answer?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Have posted an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AdMob does not keep a track of your users earning. You will have to keep the track of the users earning by yourself or by using some other service.

They will only provide you with an Video ad and will notify you once the Video a is completed so that you can award your users the points/virtual currency.

However there are other services such as [Tapjoy](https://www.tapjoy.com/) which provide ads as well as provide you with the option to keep the track of your users earning. I think Tapjoy is free to use only if you use their Ad Network to show their ads to the user, which will help you to earn and also keep a track of the earnings under one portal.